# Turn {{ }} into echo on .php page

Tags: php, laravel-blade

How do you change the characters `{{ }}` into the equivalent echo function on a `.php` page, pretty much exactly like Laravel's `blade.php` pages (if it's possible at all)?

I have looked around and the only question that's similar that I seem to find is "How to use Laravel's blade without Laravel" which is not what I want.

**Edit**

I'm posting this new data because of apokryfos's answer.

This is the function I'm running:

```
function View($view)
{
    $src = __DIR__.'/../../views/'.$view.'.view.php';
    $destination= __DIR__.'/../../views/'.$view.'.view.php';

    file_put_contents(
         $destination,
        str_replace(["{{","}}" ],[ "<?=", "?>" ], file_get_contents($src))
    );

    echo file_get_contents($destination);
}
```

From a controller, I use this code to call that function `View('welcome');`. It works by retrieving the page and that but the only problem is that it does not post the variable on the page, whereas accessing the page directly in the URL works.

This is the code on my page:

```
<?php
    $item = 11;
?>
    a php variable is {{ $item }}
```

It posts `a php variable is` and then nothing on the page, not sure why.

Comment: Open blade source code and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple thing to do is:

```
$src = "sourcefile.php";
$destination= "compiledsourcefile.php";

file_put_contents(
    $destination,
    str_replace(["{{","}}" ],[ "<?=", "?>" ], file_get_contents($src))
 );

 include $destination;
```

To echo this directly do:

```
$src = "sourcefile.php";
$text = str_replace(["{{","}}" ],[ "<?=", "?>" ], file_get_contents($src))
eval("?>".$text); //Things get a bit ugly here
echo $text;
```

The reason for `"?>"` is because eval starts in "PHP mode" by default but a properly written PHP file will explicitly set the areas where it needs to enter PHP mode and starts in HTML mode by default.

Note: Most people will say that using `eval` is bad, and while I do agree that using `eval` unchecked is indeed bad, using it on code which was read from a PHP file you've written is exactly the same as doing `include` on that file which is not as bad.

Comment: This is really interesting, i never though to use PHP this way :) thanks for this

Comment: im getting an error `file_put_contents ***  failed to open stream: No error in *path/line number*`. My src and destination are the same would this cause any problems?

Comment: @YasminFrench my bad, had the arguments the wrong way around

Comment: thanks for that, i think the way im using it is wrong? If so ill have to change the functionality of my code, ive updated my question

Comment: @YasminFrench check my update. It gets a bit ugly but it is still what blade used to do internally (in version 3) now it's much more sophisticated.

Comment: Ah using `eval()` Ive read about it but this makes a lot of sense to me! This isnt for a huge project with users inputting data, so all data entering the method is safe anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
<?= $var ?>
```

It is the same as:

```
<?php echo $var ?>
```